# Issue with positioning of one widget with respect to the position of another

Tags: python, pyside2

I’m trying to make a GUI and I have a trouble with widget positioning. I would like to tie position of one widget (A) to the position of another (B) that is added in GridLayout. So, main idea: A.pos() = B.pos() + DELTA.

In detail:

Let us have such QWidget with QGridLayout containing four Qlabels:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import*
from PySide2.QtGui import*
from PySide2.QtCore import*

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(500, 300)   

    lab1 = QLabel("label1")
    lab2 = QLabel("label2")
    lab3 = QLabel("label3")
    lab4 = QLabel("label4")

    lay = QGridLayout()    
    lay.addWidget(lab1,0,0)
    lay.addWidget(lab2,0,1)
    lay.addWidget(lab3,1,0)
    lay.addWidget(lab4,1,1)

    w.setLayout(lay)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Screen of GUI is here

[image]

So, I would like to create QLineEdit that will be placed right above lab4 and trying to realize something like:

```
le = QLineEdit(w)
le.setGeometry(QRect(lab4.pos().x(),lab4.pos().y()+10,20,20))
```

But if make print(lab4.pos().x(), lab4.pos().y()) it will print (0,0)... and my GUI will look like this

[image]

But I want it to look like this

[image]

Please, help me set my widget correctly. As you have noticed, I write using PyQT, but if you answer me using C++ QT I would be grateful too!

Comment: Placing widgets using their hardcoded coordinates is a bad idea. Why don't you place your `QLineEdit` in the grid layout too? Just make three rows and two columns grid: first row (lab1, lab2), second row (empty, lineEdit), third row (lab3, lab 4).

Comment: Dear vahancho, thank you for your advise!
I afraid your solution doesn't suit to me... In the description of my issue I've much simplified a GUI. In fact it should be a matrix with QPixmap objects that have zero space between each other. If to make rows with empty objects the space between QPixmap object woundn't be zero. So, I need to overlap widgets in some way...

Comment: You can play with spacing of the layout and margins of widgets to make them fit tighter.

Comment: why not place the widget directly in the gridlayout from the beginning ?

Comment: Dear vahancho and Cristi, let's operate with two type of widgets: labels and edit lines. Labels should have zero space between each other (like a puzzle). So, edit lines should be plased over labels and I don't know how to realize it... In simple words on the following example: I have 3 lines in my grid layout. 1st line - labels, 2nd - edit lines, 3rd - labels. So the space between the 1st and the 3rd line should be a zero and the 2nd line shold be visualized over 1st and 2nd. How to implement it?

Comment: Can you clarify: is the QLineEdit supposed to overlay/obscure the top left corner of label4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as I suspect, the intention is to place a `QLineEdit` over the top-left corner of one of the grid elements then you can take advantage of the fact that...

1. `QGridLayout` allows multiple items to be added to the same cell.
2. It also allows you to [add a `QLayout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addLayout) to a cell.

Firstly, create a class that inherits from `QGridLayout` and really does nothing more than add a `QLineEdit` to cell(0, 0) and a stretch to the right and below the `QLineEdit`...

```
class line_edit_overlay(QGridLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(line_edit_overlay, self).__init__()
        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.addWidget(self.line_edit, 0, 0);
        self.setRowStretch(1, 1);
        self.setColumnStretch(1, 1);
```

Now your code would be something like...

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import*
from PySide2.QtGui import*
from PySide2.QtCore import*

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(500, 300)   

    lab1 = QLabel("label1")
    lab2 = QLabel("label2")
    lab3 = QLabel("label3")
    lab4 = QLabel("label4")

    lay = QGridLayout()    
    lay.addWidget(lab1,0,0)
    lay.addWidget(lab2,0,1)
    lay.addWidget(lab3,1,0)
    lay.addWidget(lab4,1,1)

    w.setLayout(lay)

    # Added the following.  Note the calls to lay.setRowStretch(...)
    # and lay.setColumnStretch(...) which seem to be required to
    # maintain even grid sizing.
    for row in range(0, lay.rowCount()):
        lay.setRowStretch(row, 1)
    for col in range(0, lay.columnCount()):
        lay.setColumnStretch(col, 1)
    lay.addLayout(line_edit_overlay(), 1, 1)

    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The above results in the following...

[image]

Comment: Dear G.M., thank you very much! It seems like a solution of my problem!